# What is the difference between object(forKey:) and value(forKey:) in UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I've set some user defaults using `let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard`, and when I'm retrieving them, I can use any of these:

`jobTextField.text = userDefaults.object(forKey: "job") as? String`

OR I can use

`jobTextField.text = userDefaults.value(forKey: "job") as? String`

in what case this will has a difference? It'd be great to know when I can NOT use one of them.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`value(forKey:)` is from [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/), and not a direct method of `UserDefaults`.

Never use `value(forKey:)` on `UserDefaults` or `Dictionary` or any other class unless you have a clearly understood need to use key-value coding to get the desired result.

When you don't have such a need, use the standard access methods provided by the class in question (such as `UserDefaults object(forKey:)`.

Comment: I noticed in WWDC 2017 - session 236 at around 6:30, or slide 52 if you download the PDF, they use `value(forKey:)` in the example for using key paths with Swift 4 and `UserDefaults`. Why is that? And what would be the reasons for using it over `object(forKey:)`?

Answer (score 16):

### 1. `value(forKey:)`

The two are completely different. The `value(forKey:)` is not a `UserDefaults-only`  method. It is enabled by the `NSKeyValueCoding`, which, According to Apple's Documentation:

> `NSKeyValueCoding` is an informal protocol that objects adopt to provide indirect access to
>   their properties.  When an object is key-value coding compliant, its properties are addressable via string parameters through a concise, uniform messaging interface.

It happens that `UserDefaults` is `NSKeyValueCoding` compliant, so people have started (not necessarily in the correct way) using it for accessing `UserDefaults`.

---

### 2. `object(forKey:)`

This is the correct way to access `UserDefaults`'s properties. Unless you do not have a very good reason to use `value(forKey:)`, always use `object(forKey:)`, or the other valid methods of `UserDefaults` (i.e. `string(forKey:)`).

---

Hope this clears things up!