# Cannot take values from other view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to take user settings details from this view controller and read these details to the previous view controller. I have tried many different ways, but I cannot take values until I visit this view controller

I have tried first method from this page [Pass Data Tutorial](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/)

This method is also not working. I think it is very simple, but I cannot figure out the right way to do it.

```
class SetConvViewController: UIViewController {

    var engS = "engS"

    @IBOutlet weak var swithEnglish: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let eng2 = defaults.value(forKey: engS)
        {
            swithEnglish.isOn = eng2 as! Bool
        }

    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBAction func switchEng(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: engS)

    }
}
```

Comment: The key to answering your question (if I read it correctly) is for you to detail *how* the two view controllers are tied together. Is one presenting the other? Is there a segue involved? Show us that code and we can probably help you.

Comment: Which part is not working? The code you provided looks quite fine. Can you show how you are trying to read this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly from this part - „but I cannot take values until I visit this view controller” - your problem lies with the fact, that until you visit your settings, there is no value for them in `UserDefaults`. 
If you are reading them using `getObject(forKey:)` method, I’d recommend you to switch to using `getBool(forKey:)`, since it will return `false` even if the value has not been set yet for that key ( [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool) )

Anyhow, if you want to set some default/initial values you can do so in your `didFinishLaunching` method in `AppDelegate` :

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: „engS”) == nil {
    // the value has not been set yet, assign a default value
}
```

I’ve also noticed in your code that you used `value(forKey:)` - you should not do that on `UserDefaults` - this is an excellent answer as to why - [What is the difference between object(forKey:) and value(forKey:) in UserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472327/what-is-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey-in-userdefault).

On a side note, if you are using a class from iOS SDK for the first time, I highly recommend looking through its docs - they are well written and will provide you with general understanding as to what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store this kind of data as a static field in some object to be able to read it from any place. e.g.

```
class AppController{
    static var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
}
```

and then you can save it in your SetConvViewController like

```
@IBAction func switchEng(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    AppController.userDefaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: engS)
}
```

and after that you can just read it from any other view controller just by calling

```
AppController.userDefaults
```

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard` is already such a static object. Setting it to some other variable is not needed.

Comment: That obviously was for example purpose, author can use any other value, I just shared the idea. He wouldn't need to pass UserDefaults.standard to different ViewController

Comment: Ah, but a good example makes all the difference. Especially when you can clearly see what OP is trying to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Using segues you can set to any destination whether it be next vc or previous:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "PreviousVC" {
            if let prevVC = segue.destination as? PreviousViewController {

                //Your previous vc should have your storage variable.
                prevVC.value = self.value

            }
    }
```

If you're presenting the view controller:

Destination vc:

```
//If using storyboard...
let destVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController

destVC.value = self.value
self.present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Previous vc:

```
weak var prevVC = self.presentingViewController as? PreviousViewController

if let prevVC = prevVC {

    prevVC.value = self.value
}
```

Comment: OP specifically said that he wants to pass the data the other way - not from the presenting VC into the presented, but back from the presented into the presenting.

Comment: Yeah, misunderstood the question. Fixed